# Software to make maps like on BBC website?

Tags: maps

I'm looking for a piece of software that can (semi)-automatically generate maps like BBC use to associate stories from around the world:

Example: http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/79577000/png/_79577534_chinakashgar1114.cxp.png

Does anyone know how the BBC does it or have any suggestions?

Software price is not really an issue, but something user friendly would be preferable.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Define 'semi-automatically'. News services often have a graphics department that are pumping stuff out quickly. Odds are it's not all that automatic and mostly manually created a lot of the time (aside from likely having some map software to use).

Answer (score 3):

I've worked at CBC for a couple of years and there we used a software called [Curious](http://www.vizrt.com/support/productupdates/35529/Viz_Curious_Maps_10.0) and the same company seems to have it called [Viz World](http://www.vizrt.com/products/viz_world/) now.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure why you would want to generate a map. It would be much easier to just edit an existing vector map. You can google search "country maps vector".

You can usually find maps that are eps files that you can edit in Illustrator and add whatever you want to them. Maps are usually separate objects so you can change colors for each country. If you do not have that then you can probably find jpgs and open in Photoshop or GIMP.